# Does an open-source Access ODBC driver exist for linux?

Tags: qt, ms-access, open-source

I am converting a Windows application to run under Linux.  The original application used MS Access database files.  My original thought was to convert the Access files into SQLite and only use SQLite going forward, which will run under Windows, Linux and OSX.  However, the customer has requested that Access files continue to be supported.

I have been looking into solutions for using Access files under Linux and here is what I have found so far:

**MDBTools** - The driver supports reading from Access 97/2000/2003 files.  No write support.

**Easysoft** - This seems to be a standard, but it has a per seat or per server license fee.

**hxtt.com** - Per server license fee.

**Datadirect.com** - Per server license fee, prices upon request.

**openlinksw.com** - Per server and per seat licensing.

The application is being written in C/C++ under Qt in QtCreator.

Thanks

Comment: You might like to look at Wine: http://www.winehq.org/

Comment: Maybe it would be possible and easier to have your application work internally with SQLite and only provide import/export from/to Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) with GPL and LGPL licenses. I did not use it so I cannot tell you about the quality of the project.