# Connecting PHP5 to MS Access with pdo_odbc

Tags: php, pdo

Hi im trying to connect php5 to MS Access on my unix server.
I managed to install & load pdo_odbc drivers.
However, when i ran this code:

```
    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=tra.mdb; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

i get this error on my page:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)' : file not found' in /usr/local/www/sks/php_access.php:1 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/www/sks/php_access.php(1): PDO->__construct('odbc:DRIVER={Mi...') #1 {main} thrown in /usr/local/www/sks/php_access.php on line 1
```

Fyi, the MDB file is located within the same page.

Comment: Have you installed the microsoft access odbc driver on your server?

Comment: it that pdo_odbc driver?

Comment: No, PDO is just the interface to talk to ODBC datasources. You still need a ODBC driver for MSAccess, which runs on your server. (I'm not sure MS has such a thing for non-windows systems, but you should anyway use a real database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PDO to work, you always must active 2 libs: one for the database (driver) and one for pdo on that former driver.

So you must find an MS-access driver for unix.

Did you check: http://www.unixodbc.org/drivers.html for example? It lists access (paid I think).

This might also help (it lists a few possibilities, even tough the question was closed):
[does-an-open-source-access-odbc-driver-exist-for-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587633/does-an-open-source-access-odbc-driver-exist-for-linux)